# Async await to save file causes "Process cannot access file because it is being used by another process" error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, file-io, async-await

I have the following code to save an excel file on the server and then read its content:

```
if (file.Length > 0)
{
    string path = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + "/CSV-import-students/";        
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, file.FileName), FileMode.Create);
    await file.CopyToAsync(fs);


    FileInfo fileUploaded = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(path, file.FileName));

    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fileUploaded))
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
        int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
        int ColCount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;
        bool bHeaderRow = true;
    }
```

The file is saved fine on the server. But, then when I try to access it, I receive "Process cannot access file because it is being used by another process" error. How can I prevent this error? Any ideas?

Comment: try fs.Close(); after your await.

Comment: Even better: learn how [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.8) works, particularly using statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost invariably, when newing up a class that implements `IDisposable` (such as `FileStream`), you should do so with a `using` statement:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
{
    await file.CopyToAsync(fs);
}
```

This will automatically dispose of the resource when the `using` statement goes out of scope, and in the case of `FileStream`, will flush the write and close the file. That's the source of your issue, so this will solve your problem.

However, you might also need to contend with concurrency. It's possible for two requests to be processed simultaneously that both need to work with the same file. You should plan for concurrency, by catching file access violation exceptions and responding via a retry policy. The [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) exception handling library can help here.

Comment: thanks for the detailed information. I wonder why would not `await` handle the concurrency?

Comment: Why would it? If anything it makes concurrency more of an issue, since the operation is being run asynchronous.

Comment: Async by definition means that multiple things can happen at once, whereas sync code blocks. However, in a multi-threaded environment like a web server, even multiple sync processes can occur concurrently, since each is request is serviced on a different thread. The thread is blocked, but other threads can run the same code.

Comment: I think you could also use the stream if you're worried about concurrency... so after your await:  fs.Position = 0; new ExcelPackage(fs); etc...